# Did Swami Vivekananda believe the Vedas were composed or Apaurusheya?

Tags: vedas, vivekananda

Did Swami Vivekananda believe that the Vedas were composed or Apaurusheyatva?

Please cite some of his conversations.

Comment: of course! He had a personal experience of hearing the vedamantras

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee What mantras did he say he heard?

Comment: he was not a mantradrasta.But He heard some one is chanting the vedamantras

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee I'm not asking if he heard someone recite mantras. I'm asking what his beliefs are about the Vedas.

Comment: Hearing vedamantras being recited by a seer of yore is not just hearing the vedamantras!

Answer (score 9):

> In speaking of the sages of India, my mind goes back to those periods
>   of which history has no record, and tradition tries in vain to bring
>   the secrets out of the gloom of the past. The sages of India have been
>   almost innumerable, for what has the Hindu nation been doing for
>   thousands of years except producing sages? I will take, therefore, the
>   lives of a few of the most brilliant ones, the epoch-makers, and
>   present them before you, that is to say, my study of them.
>
> In the first place, we have to understand a little about our
>   scriptures. Two ideals of truth are in our scriptures; **the one is,
>   what we call the eternal**, and the other is not so authoritative, yet
>   binding under particular circumstances, times, and places. **The
>   eternal relations which deal with the nature of the soul, and of God,
>   and the relations between souls and God are embodied in what we call
>   the Shrutis, the Vedas.** The next set of truths is what we call the
>   Smritis, as embodied in the words of Manu. Yâjnavalkya,

Source: [The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 3/Lectures from Colombo to Almora/The Sages of India](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_3/Lectures_from_Colombo_to_Almora/The_Sages_of_India)

This clearly shows that he considered the "Eternal scriptures" or the Veda as not composed by someone as opposed to Smritis like Manu Smriti etc. Otherwise it (the Veda) would not have been eternal in his view.

Another relevant quote is found in ["The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda/Volume 1/Addresses at The Parliament of Religions/Paper on Hinduism"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Addresses_at_The_Parliament_of_Religions/Paper_on_Hinduism), where he supports the idea that Vedas were revealed and not composed.

> **The Hindus have received their religion through revelation, the Vedas**. They hold that the Vedas are without beginning and without
>   end. It may sound ludicrous to this audience, how a book can be
>   without beginning or end. But by the Vedas no books are meant. They
>   mean the accumulated treasury of spiritual laws discovered by
>   different persons in different times. Just as the law of gravitation
>   existed before its discovery, and would exist if all humanity forgot
>   it, so is it with the laws that govern the spiritual world. The moral,
>   ethical, and spiritual relations between soul and soul and between
>   individual spirits and the Father of all spirits, were there before
>   their discovery, and would remain even if we forgot them.

Yet another quote from "Pearls of Wisdom - Swami Vivekananda", where he considers Vedas to be eternal in nature:

> Veda means the sum total of eternal truths. (VI.105)

So, he considered Vedas to be author-less.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following excerpt of Swami Vivekananda's speech at the Parliament of Religions in Chicago, on 19 September 1893, makes it clear that he held the Vedas not only of utmost importance but also that it is *Apaurusheyatva*:

> The Hindus have received their religion through revelation, the Vedas. They hold that the Vedas are without beginning and without end. It may sound ludicrous to this audience, how a book can be without beginning or end. **But by the Vedas no books are meant. They mean the accumulated treasury of spiritual laws discovered by different persons in different times. Just as the law of gravitation existed before its discovery, and would exist if all humanity forgot it, so is it with the laws that govern the spiritual world. The moral, ethical, and spiritual relations between soul and soul and between individual spirits and the Father of all spirits, were there before their discovery, and would remain even if we forgot them.**